# Connecting Java Client to a Node Express Server via specific Routing

Tags: java, node.js

In Network Programing, I'm trying to connect a Java Client to Node Express Server via Routing.There is already a connection between my Node Express Server and a Website.Is there any way targeting a specific Route from my Java Program?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do, but from what I understand is that you want to make an HTTP call from your Java Client to your Node Express Server. In that case, you can do it easily from java:

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3000"))
      .build();

HttpResponse<String> response =
      client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());

      System.out.println(response.body());
}
```

Change the part where it says http://localhost:3000 to what ever server address you have. If you are running on localhost, then just change the port to whatever port you're running your node express server on.

Comment: Hey that helps a lot!

Comment: @curious_guy94 Glad this helped. do you mind marking this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the fast answer!
Since I know where this is going, this is my code in express.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../util/db');
var uniqueid = require('../util/uniqueid');
var dbInstance = db.getDB();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const parseJson = require('parse-json');





/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res)
{
    //create DB-Instance
    
    res.send(dbInstance); //Sends my sqlite db to java on a getRequest
    
});
// POST 
router.post('/', function (req, res) {//erhält die bestellung

    dataWhichWouldBeDeleted= req.body;
    //deleteRequested Data from SQLite
```

This would be my java code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:1337/database")) //getting the correct Route
      .build();

HttpResponse<String> response =
      client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()); //sends the request
     //i am not sure if this is a get/post request does it matter in java?

      System.out.println(response.body());//wont give me anything because its a sqlite db
      //need to find a way to secure the sqlite db
}
```

So maybe you can see from my code what I am up to.
1.
I am trying to communicate the sqlite-Database from my Express to a Java-Program.
I need a Get-Request from my Java-Client (which I think is what you already presented to me)
2.
The DB should be saved on my Java-Client in a seperated Database.(serversided DB->clientsided DB) I need to do this, because I dont want a lot of data on the server. (Little Help would be great!)
After it is saved in a local, client-sided DB I will visualize the data in JAVA. (I can do this by myself)
3.
On command it should be possible to delete data on my Server via Java POST.
(this is where i probably will need help again)

So I read the serverside sqlite table now and then from my java-client via GET-REQUEST. This works by targeting a route on my express server(see the code above)
Save the data on my Java Client in a seperate, local Db.
(i still need to code this)
And then on my command, data needs to be removed from the server.

I hope it was possible to display what I am up to and its not confusing for you to read.

My tasks:
1.
sending the sqlite-db to my java client via a route.
2.
receiving the sqlite-db in java
3.
sending a post-request from java to node, which deletes certain data in the server-sided sqlite db.

Thanks in advance for all the answers/advice